# wordpress login issue

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created a custom popup login box. and use form settings like that

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

and i use input feilds like that

```
<input id="login_username" name="user_name" type="text" value="" class="pop-input surfix" /><span id="placeholder_user_login">Username</span>

<input id="login_password" name="user_password" type="password" value="" class="pop-input" /><span id="placeholder_user_pass">Password</span>

<input id="register" type="submit" value="Login" class="popup-login-btn" />
```

but it redirecting to wp-login.php except it should process the login and redirect to the pages where from user started login.

please guide me how can i fix this.

thank you all

Comment: What does the <form> tag look like when it's been rendered?

Comment: When you view the page, how does it look from "View Source"?

Comment: thank you, i fix this myself.. I was adding bad name element in the input field.s

Comment: If you fixed it yourself, answer your own question so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

actually the issue was with the name element of the input field.

When i check the wp-login.php page i discover the wordpress changes the name of input fields.

```
<input id="login_username" name="user_name"
<input id="login_password" name="user_password"
```

to

```
<input id="login_username" name="log"
<input id="login_password" name="pass"
```

So i just simply replace the names and all issues were sorted out.

Thank you all